# RecycleView grid layout horizontal and Vertical scroll android Implementation

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to make a question-answer app in which user view question and when he swipe to left answer will appear. I know that this can be achieved by using `RecycleView` and `CardView`. However, I do not know how to implement. Can anyone please help?

Please see the picture more clearer idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this can be achieved by using recycleview and card view but how I don't?

You can refer this [article](https://irpdevelop.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-a-vertical-recyclerview/) for implementing horizontal recyclerview in vertical recyclerview, Hope this helps.